# Why does OCMock not match my selector?

Tags: iphone, ios, ocmock

I have an OCMock expectation that goes something like this:

```
id myValidator = [OCMockObject mockForClass: [MyValidator class]];

[[myValidator expect] validateField: @"value1" 
                             target: testObject
                           selector: @selector(field:isValid:)];
```

Even when I make the call to `validateField:target:selector:` in the implementation, the verify of the mock fails.  If, however, I replace the selector with `NULL` both in the implementation and the expectation, then the verify passes.  Obviously, `NULL` isn't what I want to use though.  Pretty clearly the problem lies somewhere in the selector.  Any idea why this might not be working, or how I can fix it?

Comment: Could you show the code how you setup the mock object?

Comment: Can you post the definition of `field:isValid:` and the line where you call `validateField:target:selector:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled all the OCMock code from source directly in my project, and this fixed the issue.  Perhaps not the best solution, but it was at least a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your "Other Linker Flags" for your test target. Add "-ObjC -all_load". That should take care of it, at least that's what fixed it for my invalid selector problem.

Comment: My settings already included those flags unfortunately.  Anything else you can tell me about your problem and how it was fixed?

Comment: Sure, I wrote a blog post on it: http://procbits.com/2011/11/29/using-ocmock-with-mac-os-x-lion-xcode-4-to-mock-and-unit-test-cocoa-desktop-apps/